# How can I backup all my github repositories

Tags: linux, git, github

How can I backup all my github repositories. I am trying to find some easy script or way to do it

Comment: A repository is a complete history in and of itself. Just clone to whatever device you like. It's already quite easy...

Comment: Use their API to get all the repositories then clone them all? Or clone them manually to any computer/device/medium you want.

Comment: does anyone have any scripts that work?

Comment: There are some GitHub applications and actions available for this purpose: https://github.com/marketplace/category/security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ cd <place for backups>
$ for repo in <github-repo-1>, <github-repo-2>, ...; do
    git clone --mirror $repo
  done
```

Comment: I did not work :( I got a error on the first repo